# Issue with Hibernate One to One Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables ProductDetails and PartNumber. There is a partNumber field in ProductDetails table which is also the Primary Key of PartNumber table.

Current Mapping:

for PartNumber table:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "Part_Number")
private String partNumber;
```

Data to PartNumber field is added separately. Now I want to add this as a column in ProductDetails section. How should the relation be specified. Its a One to One relation. A ProductDetail has only one PartDetail. I have written something like.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "partNumber")
private PartNumber part_number = new PartNumber();
```

How should it be in the PartNumber table?

**Update**

The column in ProductDetails table is something like

Id, ProductName, PartUsed, Description.

In this PartUsed should refer to Part_Number column of PartNumber table.

Comment: What is the problem with the current setup?

Comment: @Smutje how do I specify name of column of part_number in DB in ProductDetail table? Also is the above setup correct?

Comment: The column has no name, as the information about the relationship is stored in the PartNumber-table. You can (but don't have to) add a reference to the "parent" ProductDetails object, annotated with `@OneToOne`.

Comment: @Smutje Part_Number is a separate table and data is directly added there independent of ProductDetails. Then whenever a new Product is created we refer to a PartNumber.

Comment: No problem, as long as you don't invent a foreign key.

Comment: @Smutje no foreign key but how do I set the value of the column in ProductDetails table that refers to partNumber column.

Comment: When adding a new Product, you set the (existing) PartNumber-object on the Product-object and persist the Product.

Comment: @Smutje I have added an update

Answer (score 0):

In PartNumber table annotation should be:

```
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ProductDetails productDetails;
```

And in ProdctionDetails table annotaion should be:

```
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="productDetails")
@JoinColumn(name="Part_Number")
private PartNumber partNumber;
```